# How to make a fluid width webpage have a fixed (pinned) header?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fixed, fluid-layout

I am attempting to make the header/menu bar on this website static (fixed) so that it is always present at the top of the screen, and a particularly long website scrolls 'behind' it. I have accomplished this before on fixed width websites, but this website is fluid width and I have not been able to accomplish this yet without breaking the header.

Could someone potentially tell me where/what I need to edit in my CSS? I believe I need to add a position:fixed; element somewhere, perhaps in this section, but it doesn't seem to accomplish my goal in the same way as on a fixed width website.

```
.art-header
{
   margin:0 auto;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 170px;
   position:relative;
   background-image: url('images/header.jpg');
   background-position: center top;
}

.custom-responsive .art-header
{
   background-image: url('images/header.jpg');
   background-position: center top;
}

.default-responsive .art-header,
.default-responsive #art-header-bg
{
   background-image: url('images/header.jpg');
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: cover;
}

.art-header-inner{
   position: relative;
   min-width: 840px;
   max-width: 1920px;
   width: 50%;
   z-index: auto !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please put your code on fiddle, it will help to understand your query

Comment: No way to answer this without the markup that goes with the CSS.

Comment: So you tried `position: fixed;` and it didn't work? Can you place this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8uZE5/2/ - hopefully it works well enough to at least play with the problem. Let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

try this, merge your `.art-header` & `.art-nav` inside a div, and class `fixed` to it like this

```
<div class="fixed">
    //div .art-header & nav .art-nav here
</div>
```

then add the css for fixed

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

and make some margin for `.art-sheet`

```
margin-top: 241px; /*the height of the fixed div*/
```

here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8uZE5/3/)